# Is it possible to remove systemd completely in Ubuntu 17.10 replacing with sysvinit or upstart or OpenRC

Tags: 17.10, upstart, systemd, sysv, openrc

Personal preference to run Ubuntu 17.10 without systemd as init replacement. I would like to know, if Upstart, OpenRC etc works anymore in Ubuntu 17.10 as direct replacement. I know, it will be hard to trace every services systemd has grappled and making them work with SysVinit is more difficult now. Just asking, if anyone successfully accomplished this.

Comment: just use a distro which does use OpenRC    https://artixlinux.org/

Comment: I feel you and as much as I dislike systemd at the moment, I've come to realize that I need to accommodate myself with it, as it is not going away. The major distros (Debian based, RHEL 7 and onwards) all use systemd for the considerable future. Having said that, If you want an OS without it, it will be easier to look for a distro without it, rather than try to replace it - I don't think there is a "replacement path", sorry. *Resistance is futile*

Comment: Hmm...really sad to know. No more choices, no more UNIX philosophy (KISS). I wonder what benefit this systemd has if OpenRC is running equal or better? https://iwf1.com/systemd-vs-openrc-which-init-system-is-the-best-for-you-comparison/2

Answer (score 1):

**Artix** begins to be usable. it was previously called Manjaro/Openrc and it offers both OpenRC & Runit. Beware, you need to be expert. Arch based

**Antix & Devuan** in Debian derivatives.
There also exists LMDE, but it is poorly supported by Mint.

Last viable alternative: **Calculate Linux**, but it is Gentoo based, as it will be a  whole new world for you.

A list of non-systemd distributions (revisited) | systemd-free linux community
https://sysdfree.wordpress.com/2018/04/02/135/

Comment: Can Devuan testing or unstable good enough for a Desktop distro? I hope to use with OpenRC init.

Comment: I can't say. I think so, but I moved to Arch (Artix)

Comment: Tried Devuan ascii and am disappointed, not polished enough for average user. It reminds me of 2004's Debian!. I had installed from a net iso with uefi. Wasted! Now using Ubuntu 18.04, sadly no escape from systemd! until something better comes out.